# Textarea to XML automatize the process with big files

Tags: javascript, xml, automation, textarea

**UPDATE: The question was resolved by me, enlighted by some busy guy... :)**
I have an HTML who contains a textarea called "request", I created the JS code below to transform any text into an xml who fit the needs of some business requirements, the problem is the transformation occurs one time in the first line only, I mean, I clicked on "transform txt2xml" button and only transform the first line pasted in the textarea, and did not continue with the second, third, etc.
I have to process a file who contains 300 or less elements and I want to automatize a bit the process.
**Could be any way to paste all elements in the textarea, then separate each line, transform each separated element into xml one after the other in the same textarea?**

```js
function ss2xml_v5() {

var headerPart = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><A><B><C>";
var body_1 = "<1><2>";
var body_2 = "</2><3><4>";
var body_3 = "</4><5>";
var body_4 = "</5><6>";
var body_5 = "</6></3><7>";
var body_6 = "</7></6></3>";
var footerPart = "</1></C></B></A>";

var lines = $('textarea[name=request]').val().split('\n');
$.each(lines, function(){
 
for (var i = 0; i < this.length;i++) {
  
var ID = this.substring(0, 17);
var ID = ID.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')

var NAME = this.substring(18, 36);
var NAME = NAME.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');

var LAST_NAME = this.substring(37, 47);
var LAST_NAME = LAST_NAME.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
 
var PHONE = this.substring(48, 58);
var PHONE = PHONE.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');

var NUMBER = this.substring(59, 62);
var NUMBER = NUMBER.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');


//Set XML //
var xmlToSet = headerPart+body_1+ID+body_2+NAME+body_3+LAST_NAME+body_4+PHONE+body_5+NUMBER+body_6+footerPart+'\n\n';

}

//Print XML
document.getElementById("response").value += xmlToSet;
     
});

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
Press button to transform text to xml:<br/>
<button onClick="ss2xml_v5();">SS to XML</button>

<br/><br/>
<textarea name="request" id="request">AA_Address_AA     John               Good       2025547416 02
BB_Address_BB     John               Good       2025547416 02</textarea>
  
<br/><br/>
<textarea name="response" id="response"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some code in the correct position to: Separate each line in the text, then loop the function who transform the text to xml...

var lines = $('textarea[name=request]').val().split('\n');
$.each(lines, function(){

for (var i = 0; i < this.length;i++) {
 ... ...
}
});